# Should one make a bracha on seeing geological arches, hoodoos or balanced rocks?

Tags: halacha, blessing, travel, natural-phenomenon

I am considering visiting [Arches National Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arches_National_Park) in Utah. This park has several "arch" rock formations and a few [hoodoos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoodoo_(geology)) and a balanced rock.

[Shulchan Aruch O.C. 228:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=282) states that one should make a bracha *Oseh Ma'aseh Breishit* upon seeing moutains. However, 228:3 specifies that this should not be done for all mountains, but only those which it is apparent that they are unusual and that the Creators work affected them.

If I see these arches, hoodos or balanced rocks, they are not specifically mountains. However, it is clear that G-d's work has shaped them. Should I be saying a bracha on seeing any of these?

I assume that if the answer is "yes", that one bracha suffices for all of them. If so, I have mentioned 3 types of rock formations. Is there any preference as to which of these 3 I should make the bracha upon first?

Comment: FWIW, some siddurim just say to say "oh maaseh b'reishit" on natural wonders, without getting into more detail

Comment: The *Aruch HaShulchan* ([228:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%97#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.9B.D7.97_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90)) specifies that the mountains have to be uniquely tall (like the Alps), as opposed to the *Shulchan Aruch* who just says the mountains have to be unusually remarkable.

Comment: @Fred My main question implies if these structures are considered "mountains".

Comment: In Arches NP the fins you see right after you get up into the park probably qualify as Geva'ot - cliffs. First come, first serve, as they say.

Comment: To me they look either man-made or weather-made, neither of which would get an Oseh Ma'aseh Bereishit

Comment: @DannySchoemann Yes, I read the exact qualification of "Oseh Ma'aseh breishit" in Shulchan Aruch, and it does state that such mountains need to be recognized as having been there from creation. I'm unclear on how we would know this, practically. Numerous mountains appeared as a result of erosion and weathering. The arches and hoodoos, AFAIK, are not man made. I think if they were, they would be more symmetrical and look closer to Mount Rushmore.